# Is there an easy way to manage packages/dependencies on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, path, package-management, cmd.exe

I'm not even sure if the title is what I'm asking for...

Basically, I'm sick of having multiple copies of various exe's on my system, like ffmpeg, mplayer, exiftool, etc. **I was wondering if there's a tool out there that will help me manage all these (update, add new stuff, etc), keep them in one place and make them all callable from within the command prompt.**

Over the years, I've installed a bunch of stuff like CygWin, Git for windows, unixtools and my executables all over the place. I use a combination of windows command prompt inside ConEmu and Cygwin bash, also in ConEmu.

I'm stuggling to write simple scripts that rely on these simple tools due to forward/backslash and spaces-in-path incompatibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) might be what you're looking for.